# How to construct the derivatives of a morphism between two $R$-modules?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories

I want to generalize the idea of the derivative of a mapping between linear spaces. For two linear spaces on field $k$, denoted by $V$ and $W$. Give a mapping $f: V \to W$. If there's a norm on these two linear spaces， we can define the derivative of $f$ at point $x\in V$, that is, $f'(x): V\to W $ is a linear mapping satisfying
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{||f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)-f'(x)(\Delta x)||}{||\Delta x||}=0
\end{equation}
Then, considering two $R$ modules, where $R$ is a ring, and $M$ and $N$ two modules of $R$. And give a $F: M\to N$ ($F$ is not a module homomorphism), I want a homomorphism $F'(u): M\to N$ at any point $u\in M$, satisfying $F'(u)(r_1m_1+r_2m_2)=r_1F'(u)(m_1)+r_2F'(u)(m_2),\forall m_1,m_2\in M,r_1,r_2\in R$. How to define $F'(u)$ ? I consider maybe it needs the projective limit and the universal property.I couldn't find the literatures about it. Thanks very much!

P.S. By derivative, I don't mean the $d:R\to M$ satifysing Leibniz's law.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra) may not be exactly what you want, but may be worth taking a look at.

Comment: How do you define the limit without having a topology on your field and on its modules?

Comment: @fosco, thanks for commenting! About this question, I have two half-baked ideas. First is, we can use the projection limit and the induction limit in category theory, the universal property of categories. The other is that we only consider the algebraic structure, we don't define the limit, and we put all the homomorphisms that satisfy the requirement into a space. It's just like the definition of the external derivative $d$.

Comment: Sorry, this comment makes little sense to me. A "derivation" on a ring is a broader concept than the limit of a difference quotient (you need something like a topological vector space to define the latter), and I really believe you should turn your attention to differential algebra...